# how to .write a class object attribute onto notepad?

Tags: python, class

```
class rans():
    def __init__(self,intro,body,conc):
        self.intro = intro
        self.body = body
        self.conc = conc
    def get_intro(self):
        return self.intro
    
file = open('ranstext.txt' , 'w')

x = rans('lol' , 'bro' , 'lmao')
print(x.intro)
file.write(x.intro)
```

my problem is that I want to use the .write function to write a class attribute onto a notepad file, but when I run the code nothing gets printed onto the notepad file. when I use a print statement like this

```
file.write(print(x.intro))
```

i get an error like this

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

therefore x.intro is returning none, but when i print it as a simple print command it returns the class attribute associated with it?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can't "write onto notepad". You can write into a textfile and you can then open the textfile in notepad. These are two separate steps. And maybe you should close the file

Comment: _"therefore x.intro is returning none"_ **NO!** `print(x.intro)` returns `None` because that's what `print()` always returns. `x.intro` is the value that you set (`"lol"`).

Comment: try [converting your object to a json string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and then write it to your text file

Comment: Also, _"nothing gets printed onto Notepad file"_ Notepad doesn't keep track of changes and automatically refresh the file. Reopen it in notepad and you should see the value of `x.intro` in the file. Voting to close as not-reproducible

Comment: You need to close the file with `file.close()`. If that works, please delete the question

Comment: I copy-pasted your exact code. It worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your file to write into file
use this at the end

```
file.close()
```